# VBA - Excel sometimes fails to close properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in outlook, which helps runs statistics in an excel workbook.
However sometimes it fails to close it properly, and ends up ruining the process, since the workbook is open still, when i run it next time.

This is my method for closing it.

```
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

 Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
 Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strpath)
```

...

```
xlWB.Save
xlWB.Close savechanges:=True
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
```

From my understanding it should do it.

Comment: Remove `xlWB.Save`. You've got this covered in `xlWB.Close True`. Then add `DoEvents` before you execute `xlApp.Quit`. Then update if this does the trick.

Comment: Ok, I test it, since it doesnt always happen. If nothing wrong happens, I will be very happy.

Comment: Do you already use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`? That prevents Excel from asking user input ("are you really sure you want to ...?). That could prevent Excel from closing.

Comment: No I don't, I thought the `xlWB2.Close savechanges:=True` was sufficient, but I will put this in aswell.

Comment: I'll pour it in an answer, so others can find the topic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you turn the displayalerts off? Use:

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

after you instanciate the Excel application. That prevents Excel from asking for user input ("are you really sure you want to ...?). Such popup could prevent Excel from closing.

Happened to me more than once on an invisable application.

Comment: Did not turned it off, but when I checked the opened hidden excel workbook, I saw no open notification. The `DoEvents` seems to work :)

If it still works in 3 hours from now, I will mark it answer, if you include the doevents part here aswell.

Comment: Good that you found a solution, although I did not expect DoEvents to help here. Where did you put in the DoEvents?

Comment: Where you have suggested it. I don't know if it fixed it for good, but there were no more cases of this error. I don't know what triggered it in the first place, since it happened rarerly, but it is a pain, since 10 people will use this, and it could lead to headaches.